# Play Framework annotation order

Tags: java, playframework, annotations

When I call fooMethod, I want to process first class annotation (with First.class - in my project this checks if user is logged) and then method annotation (with Second.class - in my project this checks if uses has desired rights to access this specific method. So I need to ensure user is logged first). Is there a way to do that?

```
@With(First.class)
public class Foo{

    @With(Second.class)
    public static void fooMethod(){
    }
}
```

Also I wonder why custum action ignores annotation. Code below doesn't process anotation @With(First.class).

```
public class Foo2 extends Action<CustomAnnotation> {
    @Override
    @With(First.class)
    public Promise<Result> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable {
            return delegate.call(context);
        }
    }

}
```

Similar unanswered question: [Java + Play Framework 2 with nested action compositions in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17412458/java-play-framework-2-with-nested-action-compositions-in-the-same-class)

Comment: Can't you merge these two annotations to one?

Comment: Not really. I want to use the First on whole class and the Second just somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play 2.4 there appears to be an option for this from the docs [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaActionsComposition):

> Note: If you want the action composition annotation(s) put on a
>   Controller class to be executed before the one(s) put on action
>   methods set play.http.actionComposition.controllerAnnotationsFirst =
>   true in application.conf. However, be aware that if you use a third
>   party module in your project it may rely on a certain execution order
>   of its annotations.

The note is only present in the 2.4 docs, so presumably it doesn't work in previous versions.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Unfortunately we use version 2.3.8, so bad luck for me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like at least in Java 8 you have an order in annotation of the same kind: [Java Annotations Reflection Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28067074/java-annotations-reflection-ordering/30222541#30222541).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be helpful in this case. It's about order of multiple annotation above single type (like method, class, etc.).
And I don't think that using reflection would help. I somehow have to tell Play to go for class annotation first.

Comment: But you can always move your `@With` annotation from the class level to the method so both `@With` are at method level.

Comment: Well, yea, I can, but I kinda like one annotation on class instead of hundreds on all methods (since I extend the class and want use it on all descendants).